# Android List view

Tags: android

I am trying to build a scroll-able android list view where each row item will be divided in two parts i.e each row item will have two cells/columns . Each column will show a data element .

I also want to give user , facility to add data element to next available cell/column in the list view .

So , suppose two cells of first row is filled then there will be one + sign on the 1st cell of 2nd row of the list view .

on click of + , list view should add an element to that cell and + sign will shift to next cell or next row item.

Could you please suggest how to build such view . Do i need to write a custom view for a row item ?

How to decide height of each row item ?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you Need to Write a Custom View

And in Custom View

You have three possibilities

```
View1 = One Column Data View and other Plus Button // wrap in LinearLayout

View2 = One Column Data View and Other DataView

View3 = Only Plus Button at Left
```

Based on The even Items Display 1 or 3

```
if(items.getCount%2==0)
{
//then plus button will be in first column
set third Linear Layout Visible and other gone
}
else
{
View1 Visible and other s gone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this down. 
First you stated that you want to build a Grid view. To keep it simple, the grid view should be the root layout of your activity.xml file. Within here, you will set the number of columns with the android:numColumns attribute. Here is a sample code of what that would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.app_name.activity"/>
```

Next, you will need a .java file to build the "source" which will populate this list view. You can do this by using ArrayList<> Within the .java file class, locate this GridView view group with the following code

```
   GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Now you can build the source using an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<YourElement> array = new ArrayList<YourElement>();
```

to add items to this array list use the .add method

```
array.add();
```

Now to connect the array list to the Grid view you will use the .setAdapter method and pass in the name of the array which in this case is array.

```
      gridview.setAdapter(array);
```

This is as far as I can take you. Hope this helps others as well